# Docker inside wsl2 and Docker desktop differences

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-desktop, wsl-2

I have win 10 and wsl2. 
I have docker-compose like this:

```
nginx:
image: nginx:latest
container_name: nginx
ports:
  - 80:80
volumes:
  - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
  - ./nginx/www:/var/www
  - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
domainname:
  dock.test
links:
  - php
  - db
networks:
  my:
    aliases:
      - dock.test
```

In case when docker daemon is on windows side (Docker Desktop) site opens by URL dock.test.
But if i stop Docker desktop and start docker in wsl like `sudo service docker start` site is not available by domain `dock.test` (chrome error 'connection refused', not nginx error), but available by `localhost` (2 domains configured in nginx). It seems to me like docker in wsl doesnt know anything about `dock.test`. 
Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how it works but when i put this lines in windows hosts file it works fine

```
127.0.0.1 dock.test
::1 dock.test
```

Comment: Hi Ilya, which Linux under WSL2 did you run your docker? Do you have your steps documented somewhere or did you following any tutorial material to get things working?  and if it was Alpine, would you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400077/docker-in-wsl2-alpine-without-docker-desktop pls? thx.